# register_activation_hook not updating

Tags: hooks, user-roles, user-registration

I'm using register_activation_hook to register a user role on my site, and It works. Now I want to edit the role of the user, I tried to reactivate the plugin and clear the cache and still not updating the role of the user.

To be specific I changed the 'delete_published_posts' => false to true.

[image]

Trash is still not visible